# Regex for finding /*!*/; in a file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have tried many ways of doing an re.search for the symbol combination `/*!*/;` but in vain as of now. My code:

```
    a='ab/*!*/;' 
    if (re.search(r'[(/*!*/;)]',a)):
        do some stuff
```

The above code is working properly in interactive shell. However, it isn't not working when I read and check a file line by line.

Comment: You don't need a regex to check if a literal string is present. You can use `'ab/*!*/;'.index('/*!*/')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[…]` creates a character class, which will match any single character from the characters or character ranges inside. In other words, you pattern will match any `(`, `/`, `!`, `;` or `)` character. The solution is to not use a character class, however `*` is a special character in regular expressions, so you have to escape it with `\`:

```
if (re.search(r'/\*!\*/;',a)):
   print 'found'
```

However, for something this simple, regular expressions are not required. [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) should be sufficient:

```
if a.find('/*!*/;') > -1:
   print 'found'
```